# Thevenin Voltage That Is Not an Open Circuit Voltage?

Tags: thevenin

In the attached figure from *Power Systems Analysis* (Grainger/Stevenson), the voltage at bus 4 is calculated to be V<sub>4</sub> = 0.9534∠-20.18° given an external current injection of 0.68∠-135° (note that V<sub>g</sub> is a branch voltage)

Reusing this example in a different context, the authors claim that the Thevenin equivalent circuit at bus 4 has the Thevenin voltage 0.9534∠-20.18°

How is this possible when it is clear that V<sub>4</sub> is not an open-circuit voltage?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How is this possible when it is clear that V4 is not an open-circuit
> voltage?*

The unloaded output voltage at node 4 relies on the local 0.68 amp current source and the 1 amp current source on the left. And yes, it's perfectly valid to derive the Thevenin voltage in this example without open-circuiting anything.

It becomes "loaded" when an external (unseen extra) load is connected to bus 4.

Comment: Oh interesting so an "open-circuit voltage" doesn't actually require an open circuit to be present... that's confusing! Thank you very much for the clarification

Comment: Hey Andy actually one more question on this; why do you not consider branch g's admittance (-j0.8) to be a load?

Comment: I'd have to see the full text surrounding the picture from the book to be more precise.